# Did Aaron Levenstein say 'Statistics are like bikinis'?

Tags: quotes, statistics

From a [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/726/famous-statistical-quotations/753#753) (better known as Stats.SE) answer with 117 upvotes:

> > Statistics are like bikinis. What they reveal is suggestive, but what they conceal is vital.
>
> -Aaron Levenstein

As @Dikran Marsupial points out, the quote is found in Quotations for Our Time and requoted in Oxford Essential Quotations. @Jmac-recommended: So, here are some things you may want to consider: 1) Is/are the book(s) credible? 2) Is there a direct source rather than these indirect dictionary of quotations?*

*Edit: I have seen [this](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/statistics_are_like_bikinis_what_they_reveal_is_interesting_but_what_they_c) highly specific reference to 10 November 1951, Evening Standard (Uniontown, PA). **Can anybody verify** if the following quote (or similar) appears in the newspaper? (the newspaper itself existed at that time) "STATISTICS: At the Research Institute of America, Leo Cherne began to discuss the interpretation of statistics with his economist, Aaron Levenstein. The economist said: “Mr. Cherne, statistics are like a Bikini bathing suit. What they reveal is suggestive, but what they conceal is vital.”*

*Closevoter: Notability is [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-little-book/9781292148458/html/chapter-109.html) in an O'Reilly book and [here](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780191826719.001.0001/q-oro-ed4-00016754) in an Oxford University Press book.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Scanning the [archives of the Uniontown Evening Standard](https://newspaperarchive.com/tags/the-economist-said-mr-cherne-statistics-are-like-a-bikini/?pc=29936&psi=77&pci=7&pt=15223&ndt=ex&pm=11&py=1951&ob=1&search=ym/), I find this entry for Sunday, November 10, 1951:

> STATISTICS: At the Research Institute of America, Leo Cherne. began'to
>   discuss the interpretation, of statistics...economist, Aaron
>   Levenslein. The economist said: "Mr. Cherne, statistics are like a
>   Bikini bathing suit. What ...said lo be showing improvement.
>   ...Uniontown Evening Standard (Newspaper) - November 10, 1951,
>   Uniontown, Pennsylvania

While this is a limited "snippet" view, it is unquestionably the same article quoted by your barrypopik.com link.  Levenstein may have been misquoted or misattributed by Mr Cherne or the newspaper, but the newspaper article definitely was published.

Comment: "At the Research Institute of America, Leo Cherne began to discuss the interpretation of statistics with his economist, Aaron Levenstein. The economist said: 'Mr. Cherne, statistics, are like a Bikini bathing suit. What they reveal is suggestive, but what they conceal is vital.' " from 1 day earlier in the Orlando Sentinel. https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/222436425/